# “Local” functional central limit theorem for the empirical distribution function

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, limit-theorems

This question is a repost from Mathematics Stack Exchange, where it did not receive any answer.

Assume $(X_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. real-valued random variables such that $\mathbb E[X_i^2]<\infty$. Denote by $F_X(t) := \mathbb P(X\leq t)$ their common distribution function. The regular Donsker's Theorem  states that

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
n^{1/2}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_{\{X_i\leq t\}}}{n}-F_X(t)\right)\stackrel{\mathrm d}{\rightarrow} B_0(F(t)),
\end{equation}

where $\stackrel{\mathrm d}{\rightarrow}$ denotes convergence in distribution, and $B_0(\cdot)$ is a Brownian Bridge on $[0,1]$. My question is related to a [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031189/donskers-theorem-for-triangular-arrays), which dealt with a generalization of the above result.

Let us replace $t$ by $\bar t + t n^{-\alpha}$ in $(1)$, for some fixed $\bar t >0$ and $0<\alpha <1$. Accordingly, we replace the scaling constant $n^{1/2}$ by $n^{(1+\alpha)/2}$. We obtain

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
n^{(1+\alpha)/2}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_{\{X_i\leq \bar t + t n^{-\alpha}\}}}{n}-F_X(\bar t + t n^{-\alpha})\right).
\end{equation}

My question is: does $(2)$ converge in distribution to some process (necessarily defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$)? If so, is there an explicit characterization? Has this been studied before?

Comment: At $t=0$ the limit in (2) is just like the limit in (1) at tbar $=0$  except multiplied by $n^{\frac {\alpha} 2} $and so it does not exist. You may want something based on the increments, $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb 1_{\{t < X_i\leq \bar t + t n^{-\alpha}\}}$

Comment: @michael You are correct, and indeed I am essentially looking for a way to re-normalize (2) so that it converges to "something".

Comment: clarification question , $\mathbb{E} \lbrack X \rbrack$ is for the sum of $X_i$, or for every value of $i$?

Comment: @Amir For every value of $i$. I edited the original post accordingly.

Comment: The correct normalisation is again $n^{1/2}$ and the limit is the same as (1). Maybe you meant to ask a different question?

Comment: @MartinHairer Thanks for the reply! My broad question would be: is there a way to normalize $(2)$ so that, as a function of $t$, it converges to a non-trivial limit? My motivation comes from the case $\bar t=0$, where $(2)$ converges to a time-changed Brownian motion (rather than a time-changed Brownian bridge).